# Redisplay text and image in another div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Could I use jQuery for this, and what could it look like:

Inside a calendar, marked up with a `<table>`, `<td>` etc, there's content for each date, both text and an image.

Above the whole calendar I would like a `<div>` that would re-display the content of the `<td>` for the *current day*.

I'm thinking there would be a way I could retrieve content, such as already written text and images through jQuery (I'm a rookie) and then re-display it somewhere else. For example in a `div` above a calendar.

Does anybody know how this could be done? Or would I have to use PHP?

---

UPDATE to question:
this is the code in-between the `<head></head>`. But it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    var content = $('.current-day .details').html();

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nextHappening').html(content);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It could be done with either. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried jQuery .load method, but I found out that's for more external files (I think). I'm trying to find a more appropriate method. I mean all the content are there already. I just need to call on it in some way. But I would prefer jQuery-way. What method would you suggest? Thank you for answering :) !!!

Comment: I'd use either to be honest. PHP would probably be more reliable since you're generating the table that way and if someone has JavaScript turned off it will still work.

Comment: Good point. Wise answer. It's in a WP-theme so I then would have to dig in the calendar's php-files and I'm not very good at that. And I really don't know any PHP syntax. But if You would use jQuery: what jQuery method would you use? I would be so grateful for a answer since I just strting to learning this.

Comment: If the calendar is loaded when the page loads then you should be able to use jQuery's normal document.ready call to grab the content and copy it to the div. Shouldn't need anything special.

Comment: I see. But meant, what jQuery action would you use?

Comment: You want to re-display the content of the current day only? If the container of the contents of the current day has a reference like `id` or `class` name, you can use jQuery like: `var content = $('#id_of_content_container').html();` then put it inside the div(like this: `$('#id_of_div').html(content)`). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help my but unfortunately it doesn't work! Any suddgestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `var content = $('.current-day .details').html();` inside the `document.ready()` function

If you want to do it dinamically, like on click of something create a function like

```
function copyContent(){
     var content = $('.current-day .details').html();
     $('#nextHappening').html(content);
}
```

and call on events.

[This](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) can help

Comment: Thank you Felipe! And thank you all that has contributed to my question!! Tank you, Thank you, Thank you! I now works! jQuery is so cool!